# can't access website after adding store code to url

Tags: url, store-code

I am using magento 2.2.2

My store was working fine till I added store code to urls so I am no longer able to access my website using my website url mystore.com I have to add store code to access

like this mystore.com/en

how to make resolve this problem so when someone put mystore.com goes directly to mystore.com/en

thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Create folder with the name of storecode (ex: en) in root directory.

Create .htaccess file write following code inside file :

```
**../.htaccess**
```

Create index.php in the storecode directory add following code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'storecode'; //Webite code as same in admin panel

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Then run following ssh command :
Terminal navigate to storecode directory (for example : cd /var/www/html/magento/en) path depend on different machine  : Run following command

```
ln -s /var/www/html/app/ /var/www/html/storecode/app 

ln -s /var/www/html/lib/ /var/www/html/storecode/lib 

ln -s /var/www/html/pub/ /var/www/html/storecode/pub 

ln -s /var/www/html/var/ /var/www/html/storecode/var
```

**Change root directory path according to your machine above is example of apache2**

**Admin Configuration:**

- Admin login->Stores->Configuration->General tab (click on web option)
- Change Scope Configuration from top
- Then click on BaseUrl Section : 
  Change url of  Base URL , Base Link URL  :

  **http://baseurl.com/storecode/**
  In your case it is :
  **http://mystore.com/en/**

Comment: Thank You for your response,

My stotre url is

mystore.com/store

so my local disrectory will be 
mystore.com/store/en
mystore.com/store/fr
etc ...

this is what I put in index.php

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'http://www.mystore.com/store/en';

Comment: this solution helps you resolve your issue ?

Comment: I am still having issus understanding it

please tell me if this is correct

in index.php I edited line 23 with this 
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'http://www.mystore.com/store/en';

ssh commande with this 
ln -s /var/www/store/app/ /var/www/store/en/app

thank You

Comment: You just need to add code :
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'en'

Comment: URL need to mentioned in Admin configuration I mentioned  in answer .

Comment: my sore is located at 

mystore.com/store/en

what is the correct ssh commande?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72205/discussion-between-cdzwebdev-and-shashank-gupta).

Comment: can you goto your magento root directory run following command in your terminal : pwd 


and paste path in comment .